# app.config , program.exe.config, nor program.vshost.exe.config are saving user scoped settings with MySettings.Default.Save()

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, app-config, application-settings, appsettings

Trying to revisit the app.config file for User-Scoped Settings (I have used a custom settings files for years as I've never had success with the app.config file - except reading it).
What I need to do is, at Run-Time, save a setting to the app.config file (scoped to the user, not app), but not a single example I've seen here actually works (except registry and custom settings files).
One post claimed that the current .config file used will be in the bin folder and the settings should show up (but I've tested both to find nothing is saved).
I just want the user of the app to be able to save the last folder/file they were in/using in an OpenFileDialog.
Some examples:

```
MySettings.Default.DefaultSourcePicPath = filename
MySettings.Default.Save()
```

and the other way:

```
 MySettings.Default.Item("DefaultSourcePicPath") = filename
 MySettings.Default.Save()
```

neither worked. I've also tried:

```
 My.Settings.DefaultSourcePicPath = filename
 My.Settings.Save()
```

I'm stumped as to why MSDN insists these methods would work for User-Scoped variables, when they don't appear to work at all (I can put a mark on the files for changes - they aren't even opened by the OS for changes when .Save() is called). 
Hoping to be able to use the convenient app.config file for saving settings at runtime.

Comment: Are you testing this using the debugger? Because Visual Studio won't modify your development .config file like that at run time. It uses a temporary .config file that it over-writes from the original every time you build the app or run for debugging.

Comment: Ah, I did not know that. So I need to install it first, then test.

Comment: Ok - Added setup project, compiled, installed on different machine. And, as I suspected, it did not save the app.config settings.  Something is definitely amiss here (DotNet 4.5 bug?)

Comment: Ok - there is only the application config file (which the SAVE method did not make any attempt to open) as in MyApp.exe.config
At wit's end...